How can I insulate my apartment ceiling against noise from above?
My neighbors in the apartment above have two kids. They make great amount of noise by yelling, screaming, stomping, jumping, running and whatnot throughout all day and night.
We are considering sound insulating the existing brick ceilings. I’m not familiar enough with this topic, but was reading about rockwall so wanted to hear advice on what’s the best solution to keep the noise away. When they run, from the vibrations everything trembles in my apartment, and the noises of screaming at 6 AM are not pleasant at all, so I would like to achieve as much sound insulation as possible.
Also, it’s important to mention that I have a cat, so I would like to use something that won’t be harmful to her, and us of course. I’m in Europe.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


When they run, from the vibrations everything trembles in my apartment

This shows that sound is the least of the problem. The apartment structure itself is not stiff enough to stop vibration. A bang on the floor above not only comes through the ceiling, but down through the walls to the floor then up your furniture to vibrate "everything". Ceiling sound-deadening will not stop the all-over vibrations.
To have any chance to isolate the neighbors' noise, you'd have to build an entire room inside your existing room, completely separated from the existing walls, floor, and ceiling, and resting on air-filled cushions. Your landlord may not allow such a structure.
In an apartment complex, people who have no manners and respect for others can move in. It's the nature of the beast.
Your best hope for future peace and quiet is to move to a stand-alone house, hopefully away from neighbors. Moving, of course, is expensive, but it could be that owning a home in your area is less expensive over time than renting.
Alternatively, you could try to wear earplugs and put vibration-dampening pads under items that bounce around when the kiddies upstairs are rampaging.
See my answer here on an idea to isolate a bed from vibration: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/309143/140350

Even moving into apartment in a more solidly built house would help. Many modern buildings are designed with better sound isolation.

@jpa yes in the US, often times no in Europe. I've been in numerous brand new apartments in Europe that were extremely well built but who's noise insulation would be laughable by US standards. In fact the only buildings with good insulation in Europe are pre-WWII buildings with extremely thick walls - everything built after that is usually horrible unless the owner actively invests into insulation.

@JonathanReez Citation needed.

@JonathanReez This goes against my personal experience in multiple apartment buildings in the Netherlands and Germany. Originally build in the 1950s, isolated well enough that a full size piano is barely audible in the room directly below.

@quarague OK I’m super jealous then. My experience comes from Eastern Germany, Poland and Czech Republic. It was extremely funny to see insanely thermally efficient units that nevertheless felt like a Soviet “commie block” in terms of noise.

@JonathanReez They might be 'commie blocks', meaning they were build back then and then just got a major renovation to get them thermally isolated to modern standards. I don't know enough about house building to judge how difficult it would be to also give them modern sound isolation during such a makeover.

Your best sound insulation solution you can do to an apartment you don’t own with upstairs neighbors who sound godawful is to offer to pay for THEM to get new carpet, on your wallet. Sounds like rewarding bad behavior, but it’s not. It will make it damn near impossible to be completely rude to you and having done quite a bit of sound insulation solution in Southern California, carpeting THEIR floor is about the only way you will get relief.
Also, try to record the noise if possible. Document the times in a notebook and description:

11/5/2024
15:23hrs.<3:23p.m.>
young male child screaming
11/6/2024
22:30hrs-22:15hrs
adult female screaming and cursing sustained duration of over 45min.
Personal details of argument clearly heard and transcribed.

Documenting like that and presenting to the tenants their dirty laundry…they start washing clothes more, if you understand the analogy. If not, you’ve got great documentation to take to the apartment manager.
I have dealt with a LOT of customers whose lives were temporarily tied to that 800-1,000sq.ft of condo or apartment for the foreseeable future of their adult life, due to high cost of changing to another living space.
There’s not much you can do in an apartment but talk to them nicely, but sternly. If no change complain to apartment manager. If he can’t do anything see if the apartment complex will force the tenants to pay for carpet. If they won’t threaten the tenants with eviction then as a last ditch offer to buy the carpet for their apartment on your dime.

Welcome to DIY.SE! You provide some very good points and anecdotal support. We had to slim it down some, to make it more concise and family-friendly. (Though if you could tell the neighbor EXACTLY what was heard, yes, some more laundry detergent might be used in the future...) And offering to do something for them might make them more amenable to helping oneself out with the noise, too.

+1 but a lot of people hate carpeted floors. I would absolutely refuse to do it in my apartment.

Do not try to legally argue against children being noisy. The law generally explicity excludes noise by children from noise regulations and if you try to go that way anyway it will just mean that everyone will take sides against you and with the parents.

The carpet for the neighbors is what came to my mind first as the simplest and most effective partial remedy.

As others have noted, when getting sound from an upstairs apartment, it is most effective to put the sound isolation in the floor of their apartment.  This is especially true as you say that you are getting rattling of furniture in your apartment.  The vibration for that is traveling through the upstairs floor, your walls, and your floor.  The easiest place to stop that is in their floor.  Carpet is the cheap option (as suggested here).
More expensive would be to add a floor above the actual floor that is acoustically isolated.  However, to really make that work, you want to raise the floor about two feet (more than half a meter).  Smaller amounts will help but to a lesser extent.
Similarly, the room within a room suggestion (here) would if fully implemented require four feet of height (more than a meter), half for the floor and half for the ceiling.
If you prefer apartment living, you would be better off moving to one where all this had been done when building.  It's more difficult as a retrofit.  For example, you want the floor and ceiling to be isolated from each other.  To get that in a retrofit, you have to build a new floor and new ceiling isolated from the existing floor/ceiling.  As a new build, you just need to isolate them from each other.  Also, there's more room in a new build, as you aren't limited by an existing story height.  You can increase the story height if needed.

I have never seen a modern building in Europe that had excellent insulation installed by the builder from Day 1. The problem is that insulation is hard to measure and isn't readily apparent, so builders have little incentive to put it in. Government regulations for insulation exist but are mostly concerned with energy efficiency rather than quiet living. AFAIK not a single nation in Europe has laws that would mandate insulation powerful enough to solve OPs issue (two loud, stomping, yelling kids => zero noise heard downstairs).
